# Include library only if not present

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

I was watching the Pluralsight course on TypeScript and they were talking about using `requirejs` to load libraries from 3rd parties (jQuery) with AMD.  However, the way shown looked like it ALWAYS pulled in the library with a `shim:{}` I'm curious if there is a way to pull this in only if it's not present?

Or does `shim` take this into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `requirejs` and ask for the same module multiple times, it is clever enough to give you the same one.

It does this using a cache of modules.

If the path to the module is different, it will load it a second time (i.e. the same resource with different relative paths because it is being consumed from different levels of sub-folders, for example).